# Cannot invoke contract function from Web3js, but work when invoke via Parity

Tags: web3js, parity

Following function work as expected and record all Events as expected when invoke via Parity client (Parity v1.9.0-20171208 unstable)

```
function addMember(address newMember) payable public{
        require(msg.sender == _owner); // only the owner could introduce members
        uint i;
        bool bFound = false;

        for (i=0;i<_members.length; i++){
            if (address(_members[i]._key) == newMember) {
                bFound = true;
                LogMessage("Account already exist ",newMember,0);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!bFound){
            _members.push(Member({
                _key:newMember,
                _balance:0,
                _totalTodate:0
                }));
            LogMessage("Account added ",newMember,0);
            }
    }
```

When I invoke this from Web3js using following function, it does not fail (null error object) but does not execute the contract function at all.

```
function invokeAddMember(){
    var abi = JSON.parse('<my ABI>');

    var contractAddress = <contrsct address>;

    console.log("Unlocking coinbase account");
    var password = "<my_password>";
    try {
      web3.personal.unlockAccount("<contract_address>", password);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("Error - web3.personal.unlockAccount");
      console.log(e);
      //return;
    }

    var FundSplitter = web3.eth.contract(abi);
    var myFundSplitter = FundSplitter.at(contractAddress);
    var newAddress = <Address of an account already created>;

    myFundSplitter.addMember.sendTransaction(newAddress,
            { from: '<owner account with enough ether>', value: 200, gas: 30000},
            function (error) {
                if(!error){
                    console.log("addMember - Success");
                }
                else
                    console.error(error);
            });

    console.log("Contract Address",contractAddress);
    console.log('abi - ', abi);
    console.log('block # - ', web3.eth.blockNumber);
}
```

ABI for the addMember function looks like below.

```
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "newMember",
            "type": "address"
        }
    ],
    "name": "addMember",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": true,
    "stateMutability": "payable",
    "type": "function"
}
```

Comment: The parameter sent to your callback isn't an error; it's a transaction hash. You can follow up by polling for the transaction receipt for that transaction. See the "Sending Transactions" section of https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/13/building-decentralized-apps-with-ethereum-and-javascript/ for sample code. How are you verifying that the contract code isn't executed? Try looking up the transaction hash on etherscan.io.

Comment: If transaction executed correctly account count should go high, and there should be events recorded. None of these happens.

Comment: Correction: I should say that _in addition to an error_, you get a transaction hash. Just look up the transaction receipt from the hash to see what went wrong.

Comment: @smarx , I checked the transaction in etherscan.io and found that to be failing when I invoke from dApp or even using MyEtherWallet. I could see that it fails at a particular OPCODE number and wonder whether it is possible to map that back to my source. On the other hand it cannot be anything with source as it works via Parity client.

Comment: Could you share a link to the failed transaction?

Comment: Apparently the issue found to be failure in require(msg.sender == _owner); where I have used a different account to send this particular message. This was discovered by investigating the failed transaction's  OPCODEs